# Custom Post Type Category Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a blog with a custom post type called "editorial". A link to those articles looks like: `www.domain.com/editorial/test-article`. Now if I access `www.domain.com/editorial/` it shows me a random post. How can I make it work like a normal post category so it will list all the "editorial" articles?

Comment: can you post the code for your CPT, it might be an issue with the slug or redirect parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP doesn't automatically creates an archive page for the custom post types, you need some code to acheive it.

Read [this article](http://xplus3.net/2010/08/08/archives-for-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/) by Jonathan Brinley, it explains how to do exactly what you want to do. :)